# How to implement horizontal scroll for the block which is display flex and contains other blocks which are display flex too?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

There is a panel which have **display: flex**

```
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Other elements may appear in it, which are also **display: flex;** (now it's 1 and 2)
[image]

```
.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  outline: 1px solid green;

  button {
    flex-shrink: 0;

      &:not(:last-of-type) {
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
      }
  }
}
```

When overflowing, scrolling should appear. It appears, but the elements overlap each other.
[image]

If you add **flex-shrink** to them: **0**; then the overlay disappears, but the horizontal scrolling disappears.

```
.filter {
  flex-shrink: 0; // +
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  outline: 1px solid green;
      
}
```

[image]

**How fix this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra wrapper above the parent element and  move the overflow properties with the wrapper.  Also, to prevent folding the **.panel** should have an absolute width while you have relative.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.panel {
  min-width: max-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.filter {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.275rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

button {
  padding: 0.5rem 2.5rem 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="panel">
    <div class="filter">
      Age
      <button>35-39</button>
      <button>40-44</button>
      <button>45-49</button>
      <button>50-54</button>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
      Status
      <button>Active</button>
      <button>Past Due</button>
      <button>Trial</button>
      <button>Default</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```